# python method return string rather than instancemethod

Tags: python, oop

I got a class and a few method in it

```
class ThisClass:

    def method1(self):
        text1 = 'iloveyou'
        return text1

    def method2(self):
        text2 = self.method1
        print str(text2)

thisObj = ThisClass()
thisObj.method2
```

the result i get is something like

```
<bound method thisclass.method2 of <__main__.thisclass instance at 0x10042eb90>>
```

how do I print 'iloveyou' rather than that thing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Missing the () for the method call. Without the () you are printing the string representation of the method object which is also true for all callables including free functions.

Make sure you do it for all your method calls ( `self.method`1 and `thisObj.method2` )

```
class ThisClass:

    def method1(self):
        text1 = 'iloveyou'
        return text1

    def method2(self):
        text2 = self.method1()
        print str(text2)

thisObj = ThisClass()
thisObj.method2()
```

Comment: Methods aren't special, by the way. All of this holds for free functions as well. For *all* callables, if we want to nitpick.

Answer (score 0):

in `method2`, you can call the function instead of assigning a function pointer.

```
def method2(self):
    text2 = self.method1()
    print text2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    In [23]: %cpaste
    Pasting code; enter '--' alone on the line to stop.
    :class ThisClass:
    :
    :    def method1(self):
    :        text1 = 'iloveyou'
    :        return text1
    :
    :    def method2(self):
    :        text2 = self.method1()
    :        print str(text2)
    :--

    In [24]: thisObj = ThisClass()

    In [25]: thisObj.method2()
    iloveyou

    In [26]:
```